# Protractor: Disabling the control flow

Tags: promise, protractor, control-flow

I heard that the webdriver Control flow is being removed in the future, and wanted to update my test cases.

I am not sure what is the better way to replace it:

- Async await: worked well, but are not supported by jshint.
- promises chaining: I don't know how to ensure promises chaining with jasmin.

For example:

```
it('should should clear qa cookies using the qa command', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    .then(browser.get('cookies url'));
});

it('should open product page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)
    .then(browser.get('page-url'))
    .then(browser.wait(function() {
        return element.all(by.css('locator')).first().isDisplayed();
    }))
    .then(expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

How to make the second spec to be run only after the first spec ??

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

I still recommend to use async/await. Problems will happen when you will need to work with pageobjects, save some data for future use and so on.

If your jshint is erroring, consider TypeScript + TSlint

Comment: Thank you for answering. I switched to EsLint.

Answer (score 1):

You need 'return' and for clean view- arrow functions

```
it('should should clear qa cookies using the qa command', function() {
     return browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
       .then(() => browser.get('cookies url'));
});

it('should open product page', function() {
     return browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)
       .then(() =>browser.get('page-url'))
      .then(() =>browser.wait(() => element.all(by.css('locator')).first().isDisplayed()))
       .then(() => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```